# Set different font styles for WKInterfaceLabel with multiple lines

Tags: swift, uilabel, watchkit, wkinterfacelabel

I'm developing an apple watch app - it consists of two tables that contain labels.

These labels have two lines of text, I want the second line of text to have a different font style to the top line

How can I do this in swift?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to create two labels in your storyboard, each with their own font style. Then, use `setText` to set the first and second lines.

Unfortunately, `WKInterfaceLabel` doesn't provide any typesetting metrics, so there's no built-in method to determine where a line-break occurs. If you need to determine where a line-break occurs, you'll likely have to perform your own typesetting in the Watch extension, then choose to set two different labels or a single label with an `NSAttributedString`.